# Using .loc and .replace() Together

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

How can I update a dataframe's columns values based on dictionary?

For example, I have df that looks like:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'B' : [100,101,102,103],'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]), 'F' : [128,300,1205,2000]})`

`Out[28]:`

```
     B      E     F
0  100   test   128
1  101  train   300
2  102   test  1205
3  103  train  2000
```

`dict = {300:301, 2000:2001}`

`df.loc[df['B'].isin([101,103])].replace(dict)`

```
Out[31]: 
     B      E     F
1  101  train   301
3  103  train  2001
```

This gives the proper results but doing this inplace gives a Copy Warning and I need to update the original dataframe with this logic.

Also, doing a very inefficient `groupby` & `apply` combo works but clearly not optimal.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the result back to the same positions of the data frame:

```
d = {300:301, 2000:2001}  
mask = df.B.isin([101, 103])  
df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].replace(d)

df
#     B     E      F
#0  100 test    128
#1  101 train   301
#2  102 test    1205
#3  103 train   2001
```

Or you can use `update`:

```
df.update(df.loc[df.B.isin([101, 103])].replace(d))
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used `update` before. Also, I just realized how does `replace` know what column to act on? It is never explicitly said.....does it just apply to every value in the df? If so, is there a way to apply to a specific column only just in case?

Comment: You can add column names to `loc` for subsetting and replace only those columns, for instance `df.update(df.loc[mask, cols].replace(d))` or `df.loc[mask, cols] = df.loc[mask, cols].replace(d)` suppose `cols` is the list of column names, e.g `cols = ['F']`.

Comment: Thanks also, your solution converts my integers into floats, any idea why?

Comment: Did you try the assignment option? The update method is likely using intermediate process that generates nans that converts the data type from int to float.

Comment: No I did not try the assignment option, but good call. I will do so. Thanks.